# How to retrieve data via join table

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have a user model (`Uprofile`), a group model (`Group`) and a model that connects users with groups (`GroupMembership`). The table `groupMemberships` has `group_id`, `uprofile_id` and `role` fields.

`Uprofile` and `Group` both have a `hasMany` relation to `GroupMembership`. And `GroupMembership` has `belongsTo` to both.

I want to list `Group` with its assigned users and their roles.

How can this be done with `CakePHP`? I did not find an appropriate example.

Comment: Try $this->GroupMembership->find('all');

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am answering your question or if your question is vague.

But this is a list of your Uprofile with role determined by group.

```
$options = array(
'fields' => array(
    'GroupMembership.uprofile_id',
    'GroupMembership.role'
),
'conditions' => array(
    'GroupMembership.group_id' => $group_id
));

$list_of_uprofiles_and_roles = $this->GroupMemebership->find('all',$options);
```

Does this answer you question?